# indexing a tensor with an object of type torch.LongTensor

Tags: python, pytorch

I am new to using Pytorch and I receive this error when running my code:

TypeError: indexing a tensor with an object of type torch.LongTensor. The only supported types are integers, slices, numpy scalars and torch.LongTensor or torch.ByteTensor as the only argument.

Can you please point me and the right direction and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
if os.path.exists(CHECKPOINT_NAME):
print("=> loading checkpoint '{}'".format(CHECKPOINT_NAME))
checkpoint = torch.load(CHECKPOINT_NAME)
EPOCH = checkpoint['epoch']
BEST_LOSS = checkpoint['best_loss']
model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['state_dict'])
optimizer.load_state_dict(checkpoint['optimizer'])
print("=> loaded checkpoint '{}' (epoch {})"
      .format(CHECKPOINT_NAME, checkpoint['epoch']))
else:
    print("=> no checkpoint found at '{}'. Starting from scratch".format(CHECKPOINT_NAME))

for epoch in range(EPOCH, NUM_EPOCHS):
    train(train_dataset_loader, model, loss_fn, optimizer, epoch + 1, val_dataset_loader)
    loss = validate(val_dataset_loader, model, loss_fn)

    if loss < BEST_LOSS:
        print('{} better than previous best loss of {}'.format(loss, BEST_LOSS))
        BEST_LOSS = loss
        is_best = True
    else:
        is_best = False

    save_checkpoint({
            'epoch': epoch + 1,
            'state_dict': model.state_dict(),
            'best_loss': BEST_LOSS,
            'optimizer' : optimizer.state_dict(),
        }, is_best
    )
```

```html
ypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-4c3a0a33f81b> in <module>()
     12 
     13 for epoch in range(EPOCH, NUM_EPOCHS):
---> 14     train(train_dataset_loader, model, loss_fn, optimizer, epoch + 1, val_dataset_loader)
     15     loss = validate(val_dataset_loader, model, loss_fn)
     16 

<ipython-input-14-13120db09b49> in train(train_loader, model, criterion, optimizer, epoch, val_loader)
     65         # compute output
     66         model.zero_grad()
---> 67         log_probas, indices = model.forward(batch)
     68 
     69         labels = Variable(batch['class'][indices])

<ipython-input-13-f9a47d332f53> in forward(self, batch)
     18         gene = batch['gene'][indices]
     19         variation = batch['variation'][indices]
---> 20         text_batch = torch.stack(batch['text'], 0)[:, indices]
     21 
     22         # Wrap all tensors around a variable. Send to GPU if possible.
```

Comment: In which line does the error occur?

Comment: Improve your question , include code snippet which we can use to reproduce the error and include the error details too.

Comment: I updated my original post to reflect the TypeError

Answer (score 0):

there are still problems with your question. You have not shared complete code which can reproduce your error.From the errors it is clear that you have a problem in your model's forward function.The error is occurring in the below line.

```
text_batch = torch.stack(batch['text'], 0)[:, indices]
```

The error occurs when your indexing a tensor with not the expected shape. So check the shape the shape of the tensor by using `tensor.size()` . If you need more help with your question follow the below guidelines to improve your question.

Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation. [Minimal, complete, verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: The code is rather large, so I include the link to the code that I am trying to mimic. https://github.com/reiinakano/msk-cancer/blob/master/pytorch%2Bexperiment.ipynb